# How To Access KeyUp, KeyDown Events in VSTO Words Add-In?

Tags: c#, events, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

My question is simple and you can say it as duplicate but its not like that  as I want to detect key press events like `KeyUp`, `KeyDown` in VSTO Words Add-In while development using C# in VisualStudio2015 and run other functions as per `KeyCode`.

As per MSDN documentation, there are no such events for VSTO Add-In but they are giving some others events thats are like them as `Document.SelectionChange Event` and `ApplicationEvents4_Event.WindowSelectionChange` event but they are not as per requirements.

So is there any way to make it as per my question in easy way using C#...???

**What I have read:**

There are many related questions asked on StackOverflow but none of them is as per my question.

- [Detecting text changes in Word 2016 from VSTO add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770647/detecting-text-changes-in-word-2016-from-vsto-add-in)
- [MS Word's Add-in TextChange Event in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317008/ms-words-add-in-textchange-event-in-c-sharp)
- [How to get the “KeyPress” event from a Word 2010 Addin (developed in
  C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120199/how-to-get-the-keypress-event-from-a-word-2010-addin-developed-in-c)
- [Capturing keydown event of MS Word using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000645/capturing-keydown-event-of-ms-word-using-c-sharp)
- [How to raise an event on MS word Keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052123/how-to-raise-an-event-on-ms-word-keypress)
- [How to trap keypress event in MSword using VSTO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230652/how-to-trap-keypress-event-in-msword-using-vsto)

**What I am trying:**

I am trying the below code shared at [A Simple C# Global Low Level Keyboard Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook) and this one is working fine but only capturing events when clicked outside the Microsoft Word. Its not capturing event while typing in Word. I also want to just capture and run my own functions on events and don't want to interpt his own function like typing letters or etc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word;
// Added Extra Namespaces
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Utilities;

namespace WordAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.A);
            gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.B);
            gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);
            gkh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {                
            gkh.KeyDown -= new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);
            gkh.KeyUp -= new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);
        }        

        void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Up\t" + e.KeyCode.ToString());
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Down\t" + e.KeyCode.ToString());
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

and my main class file is...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Utilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A class that manages a global low level keyboard hook
    /// </summary>
    class globalKeyboardHook
    {
        #region Constant, Structure and Delegate Definitions
        /// <summary>
        /// defines the callback type for the hook
        /// </summary>
        public delegate int keyboardHookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);

        public struct keyboardHookStruct
        {
            public int vkCode;
            public int scanCode;
            public int flags;
            public int time;
            public int dwExtraInfo;
        }

        const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
        const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
        const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;
        #endregion

        #region Instance Variables
        /// <summary>
        /// The collections of keys to watch for
        /// </summary>
        public List<Keys> HookedKeys = new List<Keys>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Handle to the hook, need this to unhook and call the next hook
        /// </summary>
        IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;
        #endregion

        #region Events
        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when one of the hooked keys is pressed
        /// </summary>
        public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;
        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when one of the hooked keys is released
        /// </summary>
        public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;
        #endregion

        #region Constructors and Destructors
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="globalKeyboardHook"/> class and installs the keyboard hook.
        /// </summary>
        public globalKeyboardHook()
        {
            hook();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Releases unmanaged resources and performs other cleanup operations before the
        /// <see cref="globalKeyboardHook"/> is reclaimed by garbage collection and uninstalls the keyboard hook.
        /// </summary>
        ~globalKeyboardHook()
        {
            unhook();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Installs the global hook
        /// </summary>
        public void hook()
        {
            IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
            hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProc, hInstance, 0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Uninstalls the global hook
        /// </summary>
        public void unhook()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The callback for the keyboard hook
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="code">The hook code, if it isn't >= 0, the function shouldn't do anyting</param>
        /// <param name="wParam">The event type</param>
        /// <param name="lParam">The keyhook event information</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int hookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam)
        {
            if (code >= 0)
            {
                Keys key = (Keys)lParam.vkCode;
                if (HookedKeys.Contains(key))
                {
                    KeyEventArgs kea = new KeyEventArgs(key);
                    if ((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) && (KeyDown != null))
                    {
                        KeyDown(this, kea);
                    }
                    else if ((wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) && (KeyUp != null))
                    {
                        KeyUp(this, kea);
                    }
                    if (kea.Handled)
                        return 1;
                }
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, wParam, ref lParam);
        }
        #endregion

        #region DLL imports
        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the windows hook, do the desired event, one of hInstance or threadId must be non-null
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="idHook">The id of the event you want to hook</param>
        /// <param name="callback">The callback.</param>
        /// <param name="hInstance">The handle you want to attach the event to, can be null</param>
        /// <param name="threadId">The thread you want to attach the event to, can be null</param>
        /// <returns>a handle to the desired hook</returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, keyboardHookProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

        /// <summary>
        /// Unhooks the windows hook.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hInstance">The hook handle that was returned from SetWindowsHookEx</param>
        /// <returns>True if successful, false otherwise</returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);

        /// <summary>
        /// Calls the next hook.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="idHook">The hook id</param>
        /// <param name="nCode">The hook code</param>
        /// <param name="wParam">The wparam.</param>
        /// <param name="lParam">The lparam.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);

        /// <summary>
        /// Loads the library.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lpFileName">Name of the library</param>
        /// <returns>A handle to the library</returns>
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everthing should work fine if you don't use a low-level hook in your VSTO add-in.

For a working example please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33897595/40347) to the following question:

> [**Detecting text changes in Word 2016 from VSTO add-in**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32770647/40347)

In the example, you need to adjust the hook callback function to also respond to WM_KEYUP messages (currently the sample only reacts to WM_KEYDOWN events).

If you do not want to interfere with the default behavior of the key events (i.e. you still want the typed text to appear etc) you have to make absolutely sure to call `CallNextHookEx` in any case (this is currently not happening in your code).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already checked that but there, its firing three events on a single key click maybe KEYUP, KEYDOWN, KEYPRESS but I can differentiate between them. IN short, I want to add `if (nCode >= 0) { if (wParam == (IntPtr)SafeNativeMethods.WindowMessages.WM_KEYDOWN) { // Only Key Down Code Here }` in your code on keyboard keys function but not getting successful so can you make it happen in your code too...???